# Terraform: pass a list of security groups

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I try to pass a list of security groups to create ec2 instance.

```
variables.tf

variable "parameters" {
  type = map(any)
}
```

```
terraform.tfvars.json
{
  "parameters": {
    "ami": "ami1234",
    "vpc_security_group_ids": "sg-1234,sg-wxyz"
  }
}
```

Note, teffaform does not allow to use list for security groups as it requires all element type of map be the same. So I have to use comma-separated string.

```
resource "aws_instance" "worker" {
  ...
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${split(",",var.parameters.vpc_security_group_ids)}"]
}
```

I copy some online code to split the string, but terraform complains that the variable is only known after apply.

Comment: Why not use type object: https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/type-constraints#object?

Comment: @MarkoE, It works, thank you! Though It is not as convenient because type checking becomes more strict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I think you've already understood, the `any` in `map(any)` represents asking Terraform to *automatically infer* the element type of the map, and so Terraform will study the given value and automatically choose a single concrete type to replace `any`. In the case of your example here, the result would be `map(string)` because all of the values in your map are strings.

However, the example you've described here appears to me to more suited to be an object type rather than a map. Maps are intended for arbitrary key/value pairs where all of the elements represent the same kind of thing and can therefore be of the same type. Object types are for describing a single thing that has multiple different properties of different types.

Therefore I would suggest rewriting your type constraint to properly describe the data structure you're expecting, which seems to be the following based on context:

```
variable "parameters" {
  type = object({
    ami                    = string
    vpc_security_group_ids = set(string)
  })
}
```

`set(string)` matches the provider's type constraint for `vpc_security_group_ids` in `aws_instance`, since security groups don't have any meaningful ordering when associated with an EC2 instance and so it wouldn't make sense to use a list.

With this data type in place then you should be able to just assign the variable values directly, because they will already be of the expected types:

```
resource "aws_instance" "worker" {
  ami                    = var.parameters.ami
  vpc_security_group_ids = var.parameters.vpc_security_group_ids
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your extensive answer! I just feel it should be as flexible as json map but it is more like a question for the terraform community to think about.

Comment: JSON's key/value type is called "object" and so "object" in Terraform is the one that corresponds with a JSON object. If you don't wish to specify an exact type then you can say `type = any` to allow any type at all and then write custom validation rules to specify what's expected, but an object type constraint seems like the most idiomatic answer for the problem you presented here since you have two specific parameters that the module code assumes to exist, rather than it being just an arbitrary bag of pairs.